# Thread synchronized time read

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

i have multiple threads running an infinite `while true` without them knowing of each other's existence.

Inside their respective loops i need them to check the time and do something based on it before the next iteration, something like this:

```
Thread:
    while True:
        now = timedate.now()
        # do something
        time.sleep(0.2)
```

these threads are started in my main program in such a way:

```
Main:
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()
    ...
    ...
    while True:
        #main program does something
```

Onto the problem, i need all the threads running to receive the same time when they check for it.

I was thinking maybe about creating a class with a lock on it and a variable to store the time, the first thread that acquires the lock saves the time in it so that the following threads can read it but to me this seems quinda a hacky way of doing things (plus i wouldn't know how to check when all the threads have read the time to update it).

What would be the best way, if possible, to implement this?

Comment: You can know when all the threads have gotten to a point in execution by using a `Barrier`.

Comment: @dyz i was thinking about it but the main thread shouldn't stop and if i implement a barrier in each of the single child threads ```t1, t2, t3,ecc.``` won't the all the barriers keep track of different number of threads?

Comment: Does the main thread also use the time? And no, they all share the same barrier.

Comment: @dyz the main thread doesn't use the time only the child threads, what i mean is: If i create the barrier in the child threads there will be a different barrier for every thread right?

Comment: Don't create barriers inside the threads.

Comment: @dyz so you are saying to create the barrier in the main thread and then pass it to the child threads? But still, how do i make sure they all get the same time when they check?

Comment: @JohnSmith, [why do you want to do this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/145937)?  What are you trying to accomplish, in plain language?

Comment: @pilcrow main thread is a server waiting for requests so i can't have it stop, the child threads check the time and based on it perform some operations on the server and they need to all have the same time when they check it.

Comment: Re, "i need all the threads running to receive the same time when they check for it." But, the whole point of `timedate.now()` is that it returns the _current_ time. Are you saying that you need all of the loops to run in lock-step with each other? In that case, why use multiple threads? Why not just use one thread?